# Why not run high power truck-mounted electronics from the truck's engine?

Tags: automotive, generator

At [Burning Man](http://www.burningman.com), I see a lot of "[art cars](http://www.google.com/search?q=burning%20man%20art%20cars&hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=Ai9IUPr6E4uCyAGan4H4Cg&ved=0CCAQsAQ&biw=1024&bih=768http://)" based on internal combustion engine platforms using generators separate to the original vehicle's engine to power their LED displays and sound systems.

Why do they do this? A [typical truck engine might produce 200-400kW](http://www.volvotrucks.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/VTNA_Tree/ILF/Products/Powertrain/power_ratings_050510.pdf) and even an extremely large LED array and sound system would only consume a few kW at most. Wouldn't it be simpler and more efficient to upgrade the original vehicle's alternator to supply the required power rather than adding a whole additional engine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A typical truck engine might produce 200-400kW [...]

That is mechanical power. Electrical power is generated in the alternator, and thouse typically generate power in the order of 1 kW, as that is enough to power the lights and charge the battery etc.

The dedicated power generators are also more fuel-efficient, and can produce higher voltages - a big truck operates at only 24 Volts. Light and sound installations in the multi-kW range will usually need 110 or 230 Volts to operate.

EDIT:

> Wouldn't it be simpler and more efficient to upgrade the original vehicle's alternator

It would be simpler only when there is space available for a bigger alternator and when there is a bigger one actually available.

But it would *never* be more efficent in fuel: The generators engine is highly optimized for its task (hopefully), and will be operated at or near its point of maximum efficiency. It will also be a lot smaller, as you need only a few kW instead of 100 or more. This has a big effect in fuel consumption.

Comment: Agreed the 200-400kW the engine produces is mechanical power but I'd have thought pushing more of that through a beefy alternator would be more efficient than a totally separate engine. Most LED lighting systems operate on 5-12V DC, so the 24V would be an advantage. The sound you might need 110-230V for though.

Comment: I've clarified the question slightly to acknowledge the original alternator might need to be beefed up.

Comment: @Robert: It's not just beefing up the alternator, if you can even find one. What about the pulleys, belts, etc? And then you're stuck with a larger and heavier alternator the rest of the time when you're not trying to produce a lot of electricity. A separate generator more easily lets the system be tested from wall power before moving it to a truck too. At a few kW, I'd rather deal with 110 V than the very high current and associated waste and large cables at 12 V or even 24 V.

Comment: It's actually quite common in high-load situations to simply install a **second alternator**. For example, most ambulances have a second alternator to run all the equipment.

Comment: I understand it gets complex quickly, but my intuition was that having a whole separate *engine* would be even more complex. Guess it's one of those things where theory is just different to practice.

Comment: @Fake: But what is the cost of having a second alternator installed after the fact as apposed to buying a generator off the shelf? I just checked, and Home Depot sells a 2 kW generator for uner $200.  There is no way you'd get a second alternator installed for that price.  Special cases like ambulances are different since they can be designed up front with the extra electric power need in mind.

Comment: The specific example I had in mind was a large-ish truck with two (count 'em!) generators to power the lights and sound, and I'd heard the owners say they kept cutting out. From the size of the two generators I'd say they'd be in the region of 10kW total. I guess there's a crossover point where its better/cheaper to get a second or third alternator and these guys may have been near it.

Comment: @Robert: Also keep in mind this is Burning Man, not a electrical engineering convention.  There is a good chance that whatever was lying around was thrown together to make things work.  It only has to work for a week and it doesn't have to be optimal.  The people building these things are more likely to have majored in art and applied psychoactive chemistry than any kind of engineering.

Comment: Heh. I wouldn't be so sure Olin. There's some pretty sweet "bush engineering" going around on the Playa. It's often used as a proving ground for some pretty novel technology. See http://gwob.org/communicating-in-the-middle-of-nowhere-with-openbts/ for an example...

Comment: @OlinLathrop - They actually make bolt-on secondary alternators (at least for some engines). Installation isn't that big of a deal, I believe.